# Woocommerce API error woocommerce_api_no_route

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote a payment gateway for Woocommerce.
The gateway recieves a callback, when the payment has been processed successfully.

```
class WC_FooBar_Payment extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
....
add_action('woocommerce_api_'.strtolower(get_class($this)), array($this, 'handle_callback'));
}

function handle_callback() {
 // unlock items...
 exit; 
     }
```

I'm using wc-api v3. I created an api-user and generated a key and secret for this user.

When I try to do the callback manually like this...

```
   mydomain.com/wordpress/wc-api/v3/wc_foobar_payment?consumer_key=ck_mykey&consumer_secret=cs_mysecret
```

...Woocommerce will return:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"}]}
```

I can access official api functions like `/wc-api/v3/orders...` without problems.

The PaymentModule is active, it's just the callback which won't work.

Edit:
I just created a new class but I still can't create api-callback hooks :(. Can anyone provide some example files?